# Is there a solution for USB Multiplexing, i.e. passing data between different devices by sharing/splitting a USB connection?

Tags: computer-engineering, computer-hardware

Forgive me if my title is vague, I will attempt to explain my issue. I don't know if such a solution exists and I have tried searching without any luck.

I would like to utilize a passive USB protocol analyzer, a la the ["Beagle"](https://www.totalphase.com/products/beagle-usb5000-v2-ultimate/) to sit in between an embedded hardware device, which will be [fuzzing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuzzing) another embedded device (running a Linux-like OS), and a PC controlling the fuzzing device, as well as performing analysis on the data the Beagle will be collecting.

I need to be able to control the fuzzer from the same PC that acts as the analyzer (receives the USB packets) as well as connect the fuzzer AND the Beagle to the target. Does a solution like this exist?

I don't think that the USB splitters will work for me because I think that the splitters also act as chargers and will only send data from one end at a time. I don't think USB hubs, that act like switches, will work either. Instead, I am looking for a device built specifically for my issue. If I have to do something custom, I am also willing to try that as well if I can get some guidance.

I have drawn a diagram that hopefully explains what I want the setup to be as best as I can. [Original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HLZ0Q.jpg).  I haven't drawn any technical diagrams before, so please excuse me if I am missing some details.

[image: diagram of proposed USB multiplexer solution]

If there is a better stack exchange community where my post is better suited, please let me know.

Looking forward to getting some guidance.

Comment: "multiplexing" is the wrong word. You just want to be able to observe the USB signals passing through the wire?